# Replace keys in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects and want to replace a specific key in all objects.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var json = [{
  acceleration: 15,
  cylinders:    4,
  displacement: 98,
  horsepower:   80

}, {
  acceleration: 14,
  cylinders:    8,
  displacement: 307,
  horsepower:   130      
}];
```

For example  horsepower --> color.

A solution could be

```
var json = [{
  acceleration: 15,
  cylinders:    4,
  displacement: 98,
  color:   80

}, {
  acceleration: 14,
  cylinders:    8,
  displacement: 307,
  color:   130      
}];
```

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: You can do that with a loop. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ssJc/) with an example solution.
Use `delete` to delete a property and just add another property with the previous value:

```
_.each(json, function(element) {
    var val = element.horsepower;
    delete element.horsepower;
    element.color = val;
});
```

ps. used [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#each) for coding convenience, plain javascript would be:

```
var i;
for (i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
    var element = json[i];
    var val = element.horsepower;
    delete element.horsepower;
    element.color = val;
}
```

Comment: thank you! but does not work, because I use javascriptm no underscore

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = [{
  acceleration: 15,
  cylinders:    4,
  displacement: 98,
  horsepower:   80

}, {
  acceleration: 14,
  cylinders:    8,
  displacement: 307,
  horsepower:   130      
}];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var horsepower = array[i].horsepower;
    array[i].horsepower = undefined;
    array[i].color = horsepower;
}
```

Comment: You should do a delete rather then an undefined, since the horsepower will remain.